# Scatter plotting pandas DataFrame with categorically labeled rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, scatter-plot

I would like to produce a scatter plot of pandas DataFrame with categorical row and column labels using `matplotlib`. A sample DataFrame looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2], "b": [3,4]}, index=["c","d"])
#   a  b
#c  1  2
#d  3  4
```

The marker size is the function of the respective DataFrame values. So far, I came up with an awkward solution that essentially enumerates the rows and columns, plots the data, and then reconstructs the labels:

```
flat = df.reset_index(drop=True).T.reset_index(drop=True).T.stack().reset_index()
#   level_0  level_1  0
#0        0        0  1
#1        0        1  2
#2        1        0  3
#3        1        1  4

flat.plot(kind='scatter', x='level_0', y='level_1', s=100*flat[0])
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[1]), df.columns)
plt.yticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index)
plt.show()
```

Which kind of works.
[image: Which kind of works]

Now, question: Is there a more intuitive, more integrated way to produce this scatter plot, ideally without splitting the data and the metadata?

Comment: I don't think we can use non-numerical data for plotting. AFAIK you will have to set ticks separately anyway...

Comment: I guess the question translates in *"Why has no library implemented my custom plotting wish function yet?"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe not the entire answer you're looking for, but an idea to help save time and readability with the `flat=` line of code.

Pandas [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) method will produce a Series with a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing).

```
dfu = df.unstack()

print(dfu.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

The MultiIndex contains contains the necessary x and y points to construct the plot (in `labels`).  Here, I assign `levels` and `labels` to more informative variable names better suited for plotting.

```
xlabels, ylabels = dfu.index.levels
xs, ys = dfu.index.labels
```

Plotting is pretty straight-forward from here.

```
plt.scatter(xs, ys, s=dfu*100)
plt.xticks(range(len(xlabels)), xlabels)
plt.yticks(range(len(ylabels)), ylabels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried this on a few different `DataFrame` shapes and it seemed to hold up.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly what you were asking for, but it helps to visualize values in a similar way:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(df[::-1], annot=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use numpy array and pd.melt to create the scatter plot as shown below:

```
arr = np.array([[i,j] for i in range(df.shape[1]) for j in range(df.shape[0])])
plt.scatter(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],s=100*pd.melt(df)['value'],marker='o')
plt.xlabel('level_0')
plt.ylabel('level_1')
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[1]), df.columns)
plt.yticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index)
plt.show()
```

[image]